# trying to select objects that begin and end with speicific letter

Tags: mysql, sql, extract

I want to extract the objects which begin with `a` or `b` and end with `a` or `b`.
Below is my solution. I'm trying to figure out why this is wrong:

```
select objects from the table
where objects like "a%" or "b%" and
      objects like "%a" or "%b";
```

thank you for helping

Comment: syntax is: <col1> like <value1> and/or <col2> like <value2> and so on..

Answer (score 2):

When using a comparison operator you must specify the column names on each condition. This mistake is made commonly so don't worry, you aren't the first and most certainly wont be the last.

The way this is interpreted when you run it is `WHERE (CONDITION) OR (something unknown so I'll make it true);` but by specific the column name in both conditions it will give you the functionality you desire `WHERE (CONDITION) OR (SOMEOTHERCONDITION);`

```
SELECT objects 
FROM   the table 
WHERE  objects LIKE "a%" 
        OR objects LIKE "b%" 
           AND objects LIKE "%a" 
        OR objects LIKE "%b";
```

Comment: thank you. I just found another solution, it seems not working, could you please also help?

Comment: select...from.. where objects like '[ab]%' and objects like '%[ab]'; this doesn't work as well

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @AndyTsao If my answer solved your problem, could you do me a favour and mark it as accepted? It helps me out by giving me some reputation, and will also get some reputation yourself :)